# How do you tell if your Nintendo Switch is the primary console?

Tags: nintendo-switch

I'm doing digital game sharing on my 2 nintendo switches, but i got them mixed up. Is there a way to tell which one is the primary console?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check which console is the primary by viewing your account details in the eShop.

To view this, open the Nintendo eShop on you Switch and select which account you want to view. On the top right of the screen, click on your profile to view your account details. Scroll through the screen until you come across the "Primary Console" option, and this will tell you if the console you are on is the primary or not.

[image: Primary console screen]

Sources:

- [How to Access Your Nintendo eShop Account Information?](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22318)