# Multiple Profiles/Players on New Pokemon Snap?

Tags: nintendo-switch, new-pokemon-snap, nintendo-account

I just recently purchased New Pokemon Snap Digital Download on my Switch. My husband has a separate account on our switch and was unable to play (it was purchased on my account). If he plays on my account is there a way to create a new profile or does he have to continue where my game left off?

Comment: What happens if your husband tries to open the game on his account? Does an error screen pop up or does it just not do anything?

Answer (score 1):

New Pokémon Snap doesn't allow for creating multiple saves under one profile. It relies on the built-in profile system on the Switch to manage multiple saves. If you can't play on more than one profile, you're unable to have multiple saves.

It sounds like your Switch is not set as your [primary console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/354377/276201). When on a non-primary console, purchased software can only be started by the purchasing user.

If this is the case, you'll want to set your console as your primary console so that other users on your console can play your purchased digital games.

If you have access to your previous primary console, you can deactivate it by logging into the eShop on your previous primary console and deactivating the console from the user settings menu.

If you don't have access to your previous primary console, then you can go to https://accounts.nintendo.com, selecting **Shop Menu**, then **Deregister Primary Console**

After deregistering your previous primary console, if you log in to the eShop with your Nintendo account on your new console, it will be set as the primary console.

Source: https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22448

Comment: Hi toroid, welcome to Arqade! Can you also comment on the possibility to have separate saved states when using games?